# Source that examines OT authorship

Tags: discussion

Is well known that many scholars dispute the traditional authors of OT books and dating. For example for the Pentateuch we have the Documentary hypothesis, for Isaiah's book separation in three parts, and this happens for most books in OT. Do you know any source (book or website) that examine the arguments for both sides for each book? There are many books, such as study bibles, that provide sententiously the arguments for each side, but I would prefer something with greater details.

Comment: @Richard Book recommendations are off-topic on SE sites across the board. This us no more on topic on meta than on main. [Are book recomendations considered poll/list questions?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/195)

Comment: Fair enough.  I didn't see it as a book recommendation.  Reading it now, I can see that point.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Wikipedia?

[Genesis/Exodus/Leviticus/Numbers/Deuteronomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosaic_authorship)

[Joshua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Joshua#Composition)

[Judges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Judges#Composition)

etc...